# I saved an excel xlsm workbook that had 2 macros with the same name - now I can't open the file

Tags: excel, vba

I saved an Excel file with macros. Just before saving it, i saw I had an error because I gave 2 macros the same name. I noticed too late and already pressed the save button. Since then I'm unable to open the file. Every time I try Excel stops responding and I have to close it. Is there any way to open the file to correct the mistake?

Comment: This is not a reason to not being able to open it... If you still believe it is, move the workbook in a location not input in Excel Trusted Location and when propped for maro Enabled, choose Not Enable. Edit the VBA code and change one of them name. But, I cannot believe that this is the real reason...

Comment: Does the workbook have any code which runs on opening the file?  If Yes try holding down the Shift key while opening it.

Comment: No code when opening the file. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure your routine names are not causing your issue.  Try these steps and see if it works for you.  I saved this info a while ago, and it has saved me multiple times.  I don't remember where I originally found it to be able to credit the author.

1. Go to the Developer Tab >> Click “Macro Security” >> Click the dot entitled “Disable all macros with notification”
2. Go to Trusted Locations (on the left) and temporarily >> click “Disable all Trusted Locations”
3. Go to Trusted Documents and temporarily >> click “Disable all Trusted Documents” >> Click OK
4. Now open “Allocations” or whatever file was not working
5. Do not click “Enable Macros”…instead go to the Developer Tab and open Visual Basic
6. On Visual Basic >> click save >> click Debug >> Compile VBAProject
7. Save in VB >> Save in the Excel spreadsheet >> Close the file
8. Open it and Enable Macros.

Comment: Thank you!! It worked. I did name 2 macros with the same name.